# In Sails Node JS app, I am trying to access a session variable in ejs layout but can't view it

Tags: node.js, sails.js

This is my code

In controller:

```
if (foundUser.length) {
            req.session.authenticated = true;
            req.session.userId = foundUser.id;   // returned from a database
            res.redirect("/pjadmin");
        }
```

In View

```
 <b>Count({{vm.totalCount}}) - <%= req.session.userId %></b>
```

It doesn't read the session value. Kindly help.